# Finding and fixing Blue Screens of Death (BSOD) on a damaged operating system from another OS

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, bsod, virus, minidumps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Last night I got a rootkit in my Windows 7. I think it's the gromozon rootkit (I'm not sure). After resetting my computer, I got a blue screen of death. Here's the [Windows 7 minidump](http://www.4shared.com/file/2XaXPN-R/Minidump.html), which you can download for finding the problem.

I really don't know how I could fix that. Booting in "last known good configuration" and "Safe Mode" didn't help.

I have another operating system (Windows XP) installed and tested some rootkit removal tools from it. All of them only search the Windows XP drive and I couldn't find a good one  for searching the infected C: drive (with Windows 7), not Windows XP drive.

I have ESET Smart Security installed in Windows XP (latest updates), but it does not help either.

I have a NVIDIA graphics card on my system, but how can I fix its driver from Windows XP? I don't even know it's in relationship with that BSOD error or not.

Is there a software for finding and fixing the **BSOD** problem in Windows 7 drive?
How can I see the event logs of Windows 7 with Windows XP?

In the answers I got some rootkit removal tools, but what about the finding and fixing the blue screen of death?

Please help me fix this bad problem. I had so many programs installed in Windows 7, for example Visual Studio for Web Developers, SQL Server 2008, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of malware-infection it is strongly recommendable, that you install the complete system new, or replay a full system-backup from before the infection. Even with removal-tools it is possible, that the malware loaded more programs on your system, that stay after removing the first one.

Some tips:

- a compromised system cannot be trusted
- check with an antivirus from a clean bootable medium to detect the malware in question and get more information
- reinstall system and play back the backup of your data

Answer (score 1):

Use This 
http://majorgeeks.com/Gromozon_Rootkit_Removal_Tool_d5406.html
Worked for my friend.

Comment: hi, i test that.could n't find any gromozon rootkit.but i think it scans only windows xp drive (G), not windows 7 drive (c) | i'm not certain,that rootkit was gromozon or not.

Comment: then you should search with a live system by one of the antivirs. eg try pctools, they have good software

Comment: did you try gmer?

Comment: yes, did n't find anything

Answer (score 1):

Try GMER to detect and remove it http://www.gmer.net/

If you cant access your system use a live system by one of the antivir developers out there (avast, symantec, pc tools, ...)